# Regular expression to determine if the String consists of more than 4 numbers

Tags: java, python, regex, security

I want to extract URL strings from a log which looks like below:

> <13>Mar 27 11:22:38 144.0.116.31 AgentDevice=WindowsDNS   AgentLogFile=DNS.log    PluginVersion=X.X.X.X   Date=3/27/2019  Time=11:22:34 AM    Thread ID=11BC  Context=PACKET  Message=    Internal packet identifier=0000007A4843E100 UDP/TCP indicator=UDP   Send/Receive indicator=Snd  Remote IP=X.X.X.X   Xid (hex)=9b01  Query/Response=R    Opcode=Q    Flags (hex)=8081    Flags (char codes)=DR   ResponseCode=NOERROR    Question Type=A Question Name=outlook.office365.com

I am looking to extract Name text which contains more that 5 digits.

A possible way suggested is `(\d.*?){5,}` but does not seem to work, kindly suggest another way get the field.

Example of string match:

outlook12.office345.com 
outlook.office12345.com

Comment: Can you give example matches from the sample text above which you actually included?

Comment: I might need new glasses but there's no `abc12345` in there...

Comment: Lets say a name=12sskd345.google.com

I would want to get 12sskd345.google.com

Comment: so u want to get the (Name=outlook.office365.com) value name attribute. Right?

Comment: Yes but only if it has more than 5 digits

Comment: like this ? Name=outlook.office12345.com

Comment: or Name=outlook12.office345.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `(?=\b.*(?:\d[^\d\s]*){5,})\S*`

Explanation:

`(?=...)` - positive lookahead, assures that pattern inside it is matched somewhere ahead :)

`\b` - word boundary

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`\d[^\d\s]*` - match digit `\d`, then match zero or more of any characters other than whitespace `\s` or digit `\d`

`{5,}` - match preceeding pattern 5 or more times

`\S*` - match zero or more of any characters other than space to match the string if assertion is true, but I think you just need assertion :)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AMueUX/8)

If you want only consecutive numbers use simplified pattern `(?=\b.*\d{5,})\S*`.

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/AMueUX/9)

Of course, you have to add positive lookbehind: `(?<=Name=)` to assert that you have `Name=` string preceeding

Comment: This works really well. But this would become really expensive. 

Can I do something better and find just strings where these numbers occur consecutively?

Comment: Your regular expression would continue capturing after a space: https://regex101.com/r/AMueUX/5 which doesn't seem suitable for @VatsalyaYadav 's application.

Comment: Hey, It doesnt seem to work with look behind https://regex101.com/r/JZvAHY/1

@MichałTurczyn

Comment: @VatsalyaYadav If answer solved your problem you should acceept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression:

```
(?<=Name=).*\d{5,}.*?(?=\s|$)
```

would extract strings like `outlook.office365666.com` (with 5 or more consecutive digits) from your example input.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YQ5l2w/1

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the following expression:

```
Name=([^ ]*\d{5,}[^ ]*)
```

Explanation:
`Name=` look for anything that starts with "Name=", than capture if:
`[^ ]*` any number of characters which is not a space
`\d{5,}` then 5 digits in a row
`[^ ]*` then again, all digits up to a white space

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex

```
([a-z0-9]{5,}.[a-z0-9]{5,})+.com

https://regex101.com/r/OzsChv/3
```

It Groups,

```
outlook.office365.com
outlook12.office345.com
```

also all url strings

Comment: Your regex doesn't match the one in your link. And it also falsely matches strings with less than 5 digits. And there's no indication from OP that the strings always end with `.com`.

Comment: ([a-z0-9]{5,}.[a-z0-9]{5,})+.com   try this regex.,